# R Color Every Other Row

Tags: r, format, conditional-statements, formattable

Is there a way to create an R table (I want to eventually output it as a PNG). With every other row colored? All of the options I am seeing to color rows are based on the row value and the number of rows and row values will be dynamic so I can't do it that way.

Below is an example of what I want
[image]

Comment: If you are generating the table automatically then you could consider the `kableExtra` package. It can do exactly that (and tons of other stuff) for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `theme_zebra` from `flextable`

```
library(flextable)
ftab <- flextable(head(iris))
theme_zebra(ftab)
```

[image]